# Switch statement of ranges

Tags: c++, switch-statement, range

Is there a way to write a switch statement in c++ where you deal with ranges.
case 0-10 do a,
case 20-40 do b,
case 40-80 do c,
etc.
I can write it out using a bunch of if else if statements but wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: You can have multiple values listed one after another, but I know of no way to have a 'range'. Perhaps with some tricky pre-processor (ab)use it could be done (come to think of it, P99 has macros like that...)

Comment: I don't know of a way to accomplish this in any language, let alone C++. Switch statements are generally used to match exact values, not ranges.

Comment: Chances are if you're trying to do something like this, a switch statement isn't the right construct to be looking at anyways. Generally it's best to use those when you have a discrete set of possibilities and you don't want to clutter your code with a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Pascal has this. I've always missed it in C and its derivatives. Very useful when hand-writing scanners for example, and very cheap to implement in a compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can write it out using a bunch of if else if statements but wondering if there is a more efficient way.

No. There's not a more efficient way. Not to mention that the `switch` statement is really not supposed to be used for ranges.

Comment: A switch statement will probably be faster because it will generate a jump table instead of a serious of branches. Of course this only applies for inner loops and should be profiled before.

Comment: @Jens, Hmm. Two comparisons vs a jump table with 30 entries. Are you sure?

Comment: Not sure, but does the size of the jump table influence the runtime (as long as it fits into the cache)? In theory, why should it matter if the table has one or thirty entries for a jump? But then things like pre-fetching, caching, speculative execution, branch prediction kick in and it is hard to say what happens. If it really matters, it must be measured with good benchmark data.

Comment: And its two comparisons per range, so the if-cascade will run 2n comparisons (check for lower and upper bound for each if) in the worst case while the jump table has constant complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you *can* do this through preprocessor abuse in C (although perhaps not in C++, due to some errors with P99 in C++, which I am confident could be overcome with enough perseverance).

See the following example, using [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/):

```
#include "p99.h"

#define P99_SWITCH_RANGE(from, to) P99_FOR(from, P99_MINUS(to, from), P99_SWITCH_RANGE_GLUE_HELPER, P99_SWITCH_RANGE_CASE_LABEL_MAKER_HELPER)
#define P99_SWITCH_RANGE_GLUE_HELPER(from, i, past, cur) past: cur
#define P99_SWITCH_RANGE_CASE_LABEL_MAKER_HELPER(from, x, i) case P99_ADD(from, i)

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    scanf("%i", &x);

    switch (x) {
        P99_SWITCH_RANGE(20, 30):
        {
            puts("between 20 and 30");
        }
        default: {
            puts("not between 20 and 30");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example is left inclusive, right exclusive. I'm confident you could modify the macros to make it any way you'd like, so this is a decent starting point at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map mapping keys to standard functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> dispatcher;

    // case (-inf, 10]
    dispatcher[10] = []() {cout << 10;};
    // case (10, 50]
    dispatcher[50] = []() {cout << 50;};
    // case (50, 100]
    dispatcher[100] = []() {cout << 100;};

    (dispatcher.lower_bound(1)->second)();
    (dispatcher.lower_bound(10)->second)();
    (dispatcher.lower_bound(11)->second)();
    (dispatcher.lower_bound(50)->second)();
    (dispatcher.lower_bound(51)->second)();

   return 0;
}
```

Outputs 10105050100

Comment: While definitely intriguing, you loose all manner of a performance benefit with this approach (as I don't believe that any compiler can inline lambdas), so I really can recommend it for what the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about efficiency, you could map the ranges to values and then switch for them:

```
int range_to_value(int x) 
{ 
     if (x > 0 && x < 10) return 0; 
     if (x > 20 && x < 40) return 1; 
     // ... 
} 
void switch_range(int x) 
{ 
    switch( range_to_value(x) ) 
    {
    case 0: cout << 0; break;
    case 1: cout << 1; break;
    }
 }

 switch_range(1); // output 0
 switch_range(9); // output 0
 switch_range(22); // output 1
```

Range mapping is probably inlined, but will be computed every time. Most efficient will be large switch, doesn't matter how you write it (by hand, generator, preprocessor) because it will end up as a large jump table.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
case 0 ... 10:
case 20 ... 40:
case 41 ... 80:
```

etc..